# How to make ajax call simultaneously Without waiting for the one ajax call to finis in onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button onclick="ajaxcall()">Call the function</button>
</body>
<script>
function ajaxcall()
{
      $.ajax({
                     url: 'insertdata.php',
                     data: {
                        userdata:userdata
                            },
                     type: 'POST',
                     success: function(response) {
     //I have been using the response
                                                }
                          });
}
</script>
</html>
```

### insertdata.php

```
<?php
$userdata = $_POST["userdata"];
// I have been getting userdata from ajax using post method

// Then I inserting to my aws database using api and it will take 2 to 5 seconds to get response from the api

?>
```

### Description

1. From the html code you can see that when I click the button, I have been calling "ajax" and sending the data to the "insertdata.php" and insert the data into the database inside "insertdata.php" file using "api"
2. When I click the button it's calling the ajax and wait for the response for 2 seconds.
3. After I click the button simultaneously The ajax is running one by one so it's taking too long to finis the process
4. What I need is when I click the button second time, It should run Parallel with the first ajax call instead of waiting to finish the first ajax call.

### Example

1.When I click the button for 5 times it takes 2 second to finish the ajax call so it's totally taking time 10 seconds.

2. I need the 5 ajax call to run parallelly Without waiting for one ajax call to finish to start another ajax

### You can also suggest alternative for ajax

Comment: Ajax calls are never "waiting" for a previous call to be finished. That is the whole point of Ajax, being "asynchronous"! See my answer below for a little demo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you should be waiting for clicking the button while one Ajax process is still running. The following simulates a backend process with a random processing time between 0 and 2 seconds. Simply click the button several times and see what happens.

```js
var num=1;
$("button").click(function(){
 let n=num++
 setTimeout(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/",data:{userdata:n},type:"POST",
   success:function(res){
    $("#log").append(" "+res.userdata);
   }
  })
 },Math.random()*2000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<button>send data></button>
<div id="log"></div>
```

The numbers will not necessarily appear in sequence, as some calls will "overtake" others (depending on their different running times). But they will all appear in the log section.

Comment: I need the response after process finished so i need to get the response